# Is there an example to change a CC26xx channel using contiki after initialization?

Tags: contiki

I've found the function for setting the channel of cc2240, but nothing for cc2650. Can anyone help me with an example of implementation?

Comment: Not sure if this helps:
https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/platform/srf06-cc26xx

Comment: Thanks for the comment Barry. This link shows how to configure the channel in the conf file, that is, in the initialization. I'm looking for a function which can change the channel after it started the operation and communication. It can be a function like cc2650_set_channel(channel)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function `set_value()` [of the Contiki radio API](http://www.eistec.se/docs/contiki/a00155.html#a50f9ac761c1201c2f3d68a7dd4653564):

```
int channel = 11;
NETSTACK_RADIO.set_value(RADIO_PARAM_CHANNEL, channel);
```